# How to create objects in a firebase database from Activity B/Class B and then list said objects in Activity A/ClassA

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I was following a tutorial on how to implement a firebase database on my app and I was at the step where at Activity A, I would show the objects I had created in the database from Activity B, but then an error occurred telling that the function FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<> was obsolete and that in the new version, it was the function FirebaseRecyclerOptions<>. I discovered how to code with the function but now I can't show on the Recycler View the objects that I created in Activity B, in the Activity A. How do I show objects created in Activity B in the recycler view from Activity A?

This is an app that saves notes created by the user in a Firebase Database, created in Android Studio 3.4, appCompat v7 28.0.0  and Firebase Database 16.0.5. I searched for the problem all over the internet, a lot in StackOverflow itself, but some related ones always either use ListViews or older versions. Other ways I tried was by readjusting the place of methods, variables to see if any worked.

#### Here is the constructor of the object

```
public NoteModel(String mId, String mTitle, String mDesc) {
    this.mId = mId;
    this.mTitle = mTitle;
    this.mDesc = mDesc;
}
```

#### Here is the database from Activity B

```
mNotesDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notes").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

======================================================================

I expected that I could somehow bring the database from the Activity B to Activity A by using, for example, ActivityB.mNotesDatabase but then when I run it shows the error

#### Here is where the debugger sees the error occurring

```
.setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<NoteModel>() {
 @NonNull
 @Override
    public NoteModel parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       return new NoteModel(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),                                   
         snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString(),                                        
         snapshot.child("desc").getValue().toString());
                        }
                    })
```

There is much to the code and if you need anything else from the code to understand better please ask

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: @sanoJ the error we were getting was related with the method parseSnapshot but as we continued trying things we found a solution that was to go back on the sdk versions and adopt an older method making it work again, but thanks anyway